# Whats the best way to pass an object array as an argument

Tags: c++, function, arguments

Hey guys I have an object array and am wondering whats the best way to pass it in as an argument to a function in c++.

```
Job jobs[5];
```

Job is my class and Jobs[5] is an array of 5 objects

Comment: This should be covered very early in whatever text you are leading from.

Comment: Should we edit this to read "How can I [..]" instead of "What's the best way to [..]" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example that shows how to pass the array of jobs to a function and do something with it:

```
class Job
{
public:
    int id;
};

void SetJobIds(Job jobs[], int numJobs)
{
    // do something useful with your array of jobs
    for(int i=0; i<numJobs; ++i)
    {
        jobs[0].id = i;
    }
}

int main() {

    const int numJobs = 5;

    Job jobs[numJobs];

    SetJobIds(jobs, numJobs);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Idiomatic C++ (read the standard library) uses an past-the-end pointer instead, though.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to pass an array to a function is to use `std::vector`.

Otherwise, you will have to pass the array, the capacity and the number of elements.

The `std::vector` encompasses these attributes and handles dynamic memory also.  You can still access elements in the vector by using `operator[]`.

Also, prefer to pass by reference (so a copy is not made).
If you don't change the vector in the function, pass by constant reference.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to pass a pointer to the first element and a pointer past the end of the array:

```
void my_function(Job const * begin, Job const * end);
// const if you don't modify the array values
```

This works will with how the C++ standard library uses iterators, and more over you can use the generic [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) functions to get those two pointers from your array:

```
Job jobs[4];
my_function(std::begin(jobs), std::end(jobs));
```

But how does `std::end` know the size of the array? Clearly it cannot just accept a pointer to the array element, as calling it with an array lvalue triggers array-to-pointer conversion (`jobs` is the same as `&(jobs[0])`).

Well, you can also have a reference to an array in C++:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
T * my_end(T (& array)[Size]) {
//            ^         ^
//         reference to array
// parentheses are strictly necessary:
//    T & array[Size] is an array of references (to T)
  return array + Size;
}
```

Final note: Instead of using raw arrays (`type name[size]`) in modern C++ it's advisable to use [`std::array<type, size> name`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if the size is unknown / large).